# How to design an uploader in python with support for multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to design an Uploader in python with the following features:

1. Gets upload job requests from different processes
2. Able to tell the status to calling process regarding success or
   failure of job
3. Retry, if fails
4. Prioritization of Jobs
5. Cancellation of an active job

Need the api's in python and a brief design architecture

Comment: always put in question FULL error message.

Comment: There is no error as such, it's a design question.

Comment: if you don't have code and error message then it is not place for your question.

Comment: ok, then can you let me know, which is the place for asking such questions.

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you exactly mean.
I say something as I think.

I recommend to use celery library. This make some workers which consume tasks you send.

Make workers which upload some files with celery library.

And make processes which send uploading tasks into celery(rabitmq) with multiprocessing library